# VSTS build failed - the zip file cannot be created

Tags: azure-devops

I have a VSTS build set up for my application which until recently worked.
These are the projects in my application;

[image]

But now in the build process I get the follwing error;
[image]

The log files can be viewed here; https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArKf9AZKW_zWjgw4hHkQgssNwoHd

Comment: It seems there are multiple projets in your sln file. So do you need to build all the projects, and are all of them web applications? And can you also share your project in onedrive?

Comment: I have put an image of my projects in the question. Yes I need all of the projects included. One is a web project, another is a Web API and the others are class libraries.

Comment: So not all your projects are web applications. Do you want to build all projects? Besides, did you change the build definition since you said it built successful before, and can you also provide the successful log here?

Comment: This is a previous successful build. I do not recall making any changes although I have also had problems deploying the build (see my other recent SO questions) so I may have tried something. https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArKf9AZKW_zWjg9PKBgYiC4Nu-Dv

Comment: The link you shared is not the pervious build log. And if you need to build all the project, try to use multiple MSBuild task for different projects separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. 
"The file 'D:\a\1\a\SIR\Properties.API.zip' could not be created."
The directory contains

> \\SIR

, which is invalid, it should be

> \SIR

.
This was a fault in my build definition which I must have changed after all.
I had \SIR as one of my build arguments.